# What are these Request Time Outs in Tracert?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ping, traceroute

I am having dual router/modem ( I don't know the correct term ).  IP of first router is 192.168.1.1 . This is the router which is connected to phone line. Then I have another wifi router , its IP is 10.0.0.6 . LAN wire of first router goes to the second one. And I connect my laptop to this second router via wifi.

Now, if I do a tracert of 192.168.1.1 this is what I get:

```
tracert 192.168.1.1

Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     5 ms     3 ms     3 ms  10.0.0.6
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        3 ms  192.168.1.1
```

Let me add another one, tracert of superuser.com

```
tracert superuser.com

Tracing route to superuser.com [198.252.206.16]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     5 ms     3 ms     3 ms  10.0.0.6
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    24 ms    22 ms    22 ms  triband-del-59.180.210.201.bol.net.in [59.180.210.201]
  5    22 ms    20 ms    18 ms  triband-del-59.180.210.202.bol.net.in [59.180.210.202]
  6    22 ms    22 ms    20 ms  14.140.113.229.static-Delhi-vsnl.net.in [14.140.113.229]
  7    42 ms    41 ms    44 ms  172.31.17.105
  8   207 ms   201 ms   200 ms  if-2-590.tcore2.L78-London.as6453.net [80.231.131.113]
  9     *        *      210 ms  Vlan756.icore2.LDN-London.as6453.net [80.231.131.26]
 10   204 ms   204 ms   205 ms  ae4.lon11.ip4.tinet.net [141.136.99.73]
 11   277 ms     *        *     xe-10-2-0.nyc32.ip4.tinet.net [89.149.181.197]
 12     *      274 ms   278 ms  internap-gw.ip4.tinet.net [216.221.159.206]
 13     *      280 ms     *     border1.po1-20g-bbnet1.nym008.pnap.net [216.52.95.1]
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15   285 ms   276 ms   282 ms  stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.16]

Trace complete.
```

You will see Request time out in 2,3 and 14.  In 2 and 3 what it is trying to do? Is there some issue in my settings? Is there anything I can do?

Please let me know if some other information is required.

Comment: It most likely means the device at those hops aren't answering ICMP requests (like Ping), which is not unusual for many routers.

Comment: But which device? 10.0.0.6 and 192.168.1.1 are interconnected via LAN wire.

Comment: You can't get from 10.0.0.x to 192.168.x.x without some kind of routing, as they are different networks.