# Concerned about security due to strange tech happenings at home

Tags: hard-drive, security, traceroute

I've done a little research into this but have not discovered a definitive answer that satisfies my mind with, what I would consider to be a sound reason. Can anyone shed some light on what has happened here when I conducted a Tracert search recently please?
[tracert findings with inconsistencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOqee.png)

The reasons for my trace search and investigation were also prompted by my discovering of an unknown drive on my laptop, (which I created a homepage shortcut to so I could investigate at a more appropriate time), but once I returned to check it out I discovered the following...
[mysterious Z, here then gone??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zGP4.jpg)

Any thoughts on what is happening and what actions I should take would be much appreciated. kind regards Juice [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOqee.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VzTX.png [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zGP4.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1xiQ.jpg

Is it normal for the Z drive to be visible but not accessible and then for it to change or move itself? After all, I purchased this laptop with Win10 already installed and I have made no changes to the OS at all. Strangely, if I try to update a driver I get a notification telling me to see my IT administrator for permission....

Comment: Nothing in this post supports concerns about security.  Traceroute is not a tool that can indicate security issues.

Answer (score 2):

Tracert screenshot is normal. Question has been asked many times before.
[1](https://superuser.com/questions/710471/tracert-behaviour-explanation) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1444021/is-it-normal-to-get-some-request-timed-out-in-tracert) [3](https://superuser.com/questions/989092/request-timed-out-using-tracert) [4](https://superuser.com/questions/571282/what-are-these-request-time-outs-in-tracert). The devices in between don't respond to those ICMP requests hence "`request timed out`".

Mysterious Z:\ drive is not very mysterious https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-z-drive/

*That new drive labeled (Z: ) is the restore partition which is added to give you the option of restoring back to your previous version of windows. It is nothing to worry about, and should not be deleted.*

Is your laptop in airplane mode??

Comment: Laptop is only a month old and contected to wifi whilst in airplane mode.

Comment: Is it normal for the Z drive to be visible but not accessible and then for it to change or move itself?

Comment: @Juice Well, it is a bug. But it is nothing to worry about. Just one of millions of bugs in Microsoft's code.